# UIPickerView in UITableViewCell:issue in showing the value at particular cell

Tags: iphone, uipickerview

I am using the UIPickerView in UITableView for picking the integer value. I am not getting how to set the value to the label in particular cell. Below is my code:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell;
cell = [self.mTicketTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
else{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cell.bg.png"]];
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

lblType = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 15, 90, 30)];
lblPrice = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(140, 15, 90, 30)];
lblSeat = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(232, 21, 52, 26)];
lblSeat.text = strSelected;
lblSeat.tag = indexPath.row+1;
lblSeat.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
lblSeat.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
lblSeat.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
UIButton *btnPicker = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[btnPicker setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"drop_down.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnPicker addTarget:self action:@selector(pickseats:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
btnPicker.frame = CGRectMake(232, 20, 80, 30);

self.mPickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
self.mPickerView.frame = CGRectMake(228, 100, 90, 60); 
self.mPickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
self.mPickerView.delegate = self;
self.mPickerView.dataSource = self;
[self.mPickerView setNeedsLayout];
self.mPickerView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.75f, 0.75f);
self.mPickerView.hidden = TRUE;
[self.view addSubview:self.mPickerView];

lblType.text = [arrType objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
if([arrCost count] == 0)
{
    lblPrice.text = @"0";
}
else{
lblPrice.text = [arrCost objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
[cell addSubview:lblType];
[cell addSubview:lblPrice];
[cell addSubview:btnPicker];
[cell addSubview:lblSeat];

return cell;
}

-(NSInteger) numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
return 1;
}

-(NSInteger) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
return 10;
}

-(NSString *) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
return [numbers objectAtIndex:row];
}

-(void) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
strSelected = [numbers objectAtIndex:row];
NSLog(@"str selection:%@", strSelected);
self.mPickerView.hidden = TRUE;
[self.mTicketTable reloadData];
}
```

Please guide for the above.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is this [self.view addSubview:self.mPickerView]; and  if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
else{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

Comment: you are adding pickerview in self.View in cellforrowatIndexpath method... that can't work..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to me what you can do is :

First of all assign tag to your btnPicker and lblSeat like

```
btnPicker.tag = indexPath.row;
lblSeat.tag = 11111;
```

Then in didSelectRow method for pickerView assign selected value to your array.

```
-(void) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    int index = pickerView.tag;
    strSelected = [numbers objectAtIndex:row];
    NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:0];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:path];

    for (UIView* tempView in [cell subviews]) {
        if ([tempView isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
            if (tempView.tag == 11111) {
                UILabel *lblTemp = (UILabel *)tempView;
                lblTemp.text = strSelected;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    self.mPickerView.hidden = TRUE;
}
```

Replace pickseats method :

```
-(void)pickseats:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *btn = (UIButton *) sender;
    self.mPickerView.tag = btn.tag;
    self.mPickerView.hidden = FALSE;
}
```

I think this will work. If not just let me know.
THNKS.

Comment: @iPhone : now check it out... i have edited it.... in case of custom cell what i wrote earlier will work.....but now try edited one....

Comment: There is some index related problem i think, the way you did int index = pickerView.tag giving error in "UITableViewCell *cell" line implicit conversion to NSIndexPath is disallowed with ARC.

Comment: that's ok but it is updating only the value in last cell only,  i am using through button when button clicked the picker view will show and value will be updated of the cell where button clicked. Please check question there button is taken.

Comment: can you provide me your project so i can provide you exact solution ? Because i didn't get it from your code.

Comment: It's quite simple man, what i said is that the above activity should be done on button click, there is a UIButton in tableview with labels and picker view. On button click which button is clicked the label of that cell will be updated. If any thing not clear please ask.

Comment: okay. What you are doing is on button click, you are displaying picker view and selected value will be updated in cell right? So, solution that i provided must resolved your problem. But still its not working means you have done a silly mistake. So if you provide your project it'll help me to resolve it.

Comment: The project is not needed to solve the problem, but still if you insist i can send you the class files in which this code is written.

Comment: Hey i want to ask that is picker view showing fine, means it is showing in the cell where button clicked or somewhere else because here it is showing on last cell only.

Comment: No, its not showing in the cell where button clicked. Because you are adding it in "self.view". And problem is solved?

Comment: No, i am not adding it in self.view if you checked the files i sent it is [cell addSubView:self.mPickerView]; And thanks for helping out.